# render() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given) Django view while I want to pass varibale

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-urls

I want to pass a variable to template when I get this error. 
I saw many stackoverflow answers but it tells , Django send Self by default that's why It saying I am sending 3 arguments. But whats the solution of it I am not getting

**Url.py**

```
 url(r'^(?P<lid>\d+)/labels/$' , 
 login_required(LayerView.as_view('ImportLabelView')),
 name='mapport.maps.layers.importlabel')
```

**view.py**

```
return self.render('mapport/maps/layers/Labels_detail.html' , {'lid': self.layer.id})
```

So how can I enable my 3rd argument to pass ?

EDIT :
Layerview use `from mapport.core.views import BaseView` and its code is

```
class LayerView(BaseView):
    def __init__(self):
        # super(LayerView, self).__init__()
        self.tab = 'layers'
```

Comment: Try changing `self.render(...)` to `render(...)`.

Comment: What generic View does `LayerView` subclass?

Comment: @ikkuh give error.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule  yes class LayerView(BaseView):
    def __init__(self):
        # super(LayerView, self).__init__()
        self.tab = 'layers'
   is base view

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of adding code in the comments. You haven't shown where the `render` method comes from. As far as I know, it's not part of Django's class based views.

Comment: There isn't any generic `BaseView` class in Django AFAIK. Are you using any django view library that supplies `BaseView` class?

Comment: @Alasdair kindly check

Comment: You still haven't shown `BaseView`, or what the `render` method is. Without that, we can't tell what the missing argument should be.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `render` shortcut directly as:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
....
render(
     request, 
     'mapport/maps/layers/Labels_detail.html',
     {'lid': self.layer.id})
```

Comment: 'str' object has no attribute 'META'

Comment: Please add code for LayerView in your question. Specifically the method calling render in this case.